# how to design Android Edittext with sharp edges something like facebook text boxes?

Tags: textbox, android-edittext

i want to design edittext with sharp edges something like facebook .sample code is appritiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget

you can draw 9 patch image in the shape u need and give it as the background to your EditText.

and also check this link

[Problem with EditText background (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625633/problem-with-edittext-background-android)